# HttpUtility.UrlDecode encoding from UTF-8 to ASCII

Tags: c#, encoding

```
 answers2 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Model.FindOne<UserResult>(ur => ur.UserID == user.UserID 
            && ur.ModuleID == 2 
            && ur.TopicID == 9 
            && ur.ActivityID == 2 
            && ur.QuestionID == 2).Results, Encoding.ASCII).Split('|');
```

The result field contains German characters encoded as ASCII in the SQL database. I'm using a bulk SMS sending service which requires that special characters be sent as ASCII codes.

It's not having difficulty decoding "%7C" and "%20" seeing as the UTF-8 and ASCII codes are the same for it. If I send the character in UTF-8 (%c3%a4) it works fine but if I change it back to ASCII(%E4) the SMS sends me back a question mark in place of the character.

The ASCII decoding scheme i've indicated doesn't seem to be working, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have to elaborate. The `UserResult` search has no relevance to `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` or your encoding issue. Give a proper example. How do you persist that url in your database? What type of database is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%E4` is not ASCII. If you want to use values like that, you'll have to use the actual encoding you want to use, e.g.:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2").GetString(new byte[] { 0xE4 })
```

produces `ä`, while

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 0xE4 })
```

produces `?`.

ASCII only describes the first 128 byte-values - the rest are specific encodings that *extend* ASCII. So any time you try to decode anything larger than 128 by ASCII, you'll get `?`.

Obviously, this also works in reverse - any character that's not part of ASCII (and your `ä` certainly isn't) will be encoded as `63` - also known as `?` :)